# Decodificación imagen Matlab

Tags: imagen, matlab

Un consulta, estoy empezando con el procesamiento de imágenes en Matlab, para lo cual debo leer una imagen de prueba en Matlab, sacar su espectrograma y posteriormente realizar la decodificación de la imagen utilizando el espectrograma.

Ya tengo hecho el espectrograma de la imagen, sin embargo aún no sé como decodificar la información utilizando este espectrograma.
Me podrían ayudar??

Se supone que el espectrograma debíamos crearlo con funciones propias y no con las predeterminadas por matlab, de ahí la extensión del código, según entiendo con el espectrograma ya debería poder ver cuáles son los 0 y 1 de la imagen de prueba para poder extraerlos y continuar con el procedimiento

Adjunto captura de lo que se me pide hacer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
%%
close all;

%% Obtencion de los datos.
load('image_test_1.mat','salida');
Fs = 4000 ;
X=salida';
[Q,R]=size(X);

%% Transformada Rapida de Fourier 
Y = fft(X);
L = length(X);
P4 = abs(Y/L);
P3 = P4(1:L/2+1);
P3(2:end-1) = 2*P3(2:end-1);
f = Fs*(0:(L/2))/L;
figure
plot(f,P3) 
title('Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of X(t)')
xlabel('f (Hz)')
ylabel('|P1(f)|')

%% Caracteristicas ventana de Hamming
%Muestras de la ventana
K=50;
k=round(K);
n=1:k;
%Tamanio de la ventana
N=k;

tamv = N;
nmv = (L/(tamv/2))-1;
iniv = 0:tamv/2:(L-tamv);
finv = iniv + tamv;
iniv(1) = 1;

wb=0.5+0.5*cos(2*pi*n/N);

u=0;
for i=1:L
 w2 = (0.54+0.46*cos(2*pi*i/N))^2;
 u=u+w2;
end

U=u/L;

%% Aplicacion de la ventana
vk = [];

for i = 1:nmv
 vi= X(iniv(i): finv(i));
 vi=vi.*wb;
 Y = fft(vi);
 L = length(vi);
 P2 = abs(Y/L);
 P1 = P2(1:L/2+1);
 P1(2:end-1) = 2*P1(2:end-1);

 vk = [vk abs(P1')]; 
end

PXX=1/(U*L)*abs(vk).^2;

M=nmv;

SUM=0;
for i=1:2*M-1
 PY2=PXX.^i;
 SUM=PY2+SUM;
end

PXX2=1/(2*M-1)*SUM;

%% 
for i=1:Q:50

end



%% Obtencion de graficas 

figure
s = surf(PXX2);
c = s.YData; % Extraccion de la columna Y de datos de vk.
a = (s.YData*1900/39)'; % Frecuencia de ubicacion de la muestra
title('Espectrograma usando STFT X(t)')
xlabel('Ventanas')
ylabel('Muestras (|V(k)|)')

% En esta grafica se visualizaran en que ventana se encuentra la muestra
figure
plot(vk)
title('Relación muestras vs ventana (2D)')
xlabel('Ventanas')
ylabel('Muestras (|V(k)|)')
grid on

figure
plot(a,c)
title('Relación muestras y frecuencias usando STFT X(t)')
xlabel('Frecuencia (Hz)')
ylabel('Muestras (|V(k)|)')
grid on

[S,f,t]=stft(X,Fs,'Window',wb);
figure;
surf(t,abs(f),abs(S));
title('Espectrograma de la señal usando STFT');
xlabel('Tiempo [s]');
ylabel('Frecuencia [Hz]');
zlabel('Muestras');
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Está buena esta pregunta, falta ampliarla. Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: Claro, ya nado el código